# Como chamar explicitamente e implicitamente uma Activity no Android?

Tags: android, intent

Gostaria de saber como e quando chamar explicitamente e implicitamente uma Activity(atividade)?

Se quero chamar uma Activity(atividade), uma tela interna de meu app e que faça um processamento padrão, como chamar a função da câmera ou do gps, que contexto devo usar, chamada explicita ou implícita?

Se quero chamar um recurso nativo do Android, ou de terceiro(de outro aplicativo), que contexto devo usar, chamada explicita ou implícita?

Comment: Eu não votei negativo na sua pergunta, mas me parece pouco elaborada e sem contexto. Dá impressão que vc perguntou de qq jeito só pra poder postar a resposta. Acho que se [edit] e elaborar melhor, contextualizar o uso, e quem sabe detalhar uma necessidade real de uso, pode ser mais bem recebida. O único cuidado, agora que a pergunta já tem mais de uma resposta, é editar sem mudar a dúvida principal, para não invalidar as postagens de terceiros. Aqui tem umas dicas para elaborar perguntas: [ask]

Answer (score 6):

1 -  Implicitamente:

No `AndroidManifest.xml` declare um `intent filter` para a sua `activity`:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.counter.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.counter.MainAction" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
<activity>
```

Depois você chama a sua `Activity`:

```
Intent i=new Intent ("com.example.counter.MainAction");
startActivity(i);
```

2 - Explicitamente.

Você utiliza do mesmo modo da anterior porém no construtor do `intent` você precisa passar os parâmetros  a `activity` atual e a próxima activity.

```
Intent i=new Intent (this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

Para chamar sua Activity explicitamente, você fará uso do `Intent`:

A Intent é um objeto de mensagem que pode ser usado para solicitar uma ação de outro componente de aplicativo.

Botão `Próximo` na tela `activity_nome.xml`:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_prox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edt_nome"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_prox"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:onClick="next" />
```

Método `next` no Arquivo `NomeActivity.java`, dessa maneira:

```
public void next(View view) {

Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmailActivity.class);
startActivity(intent); 

}
```

Veja acima, imaginando que você tenha um botão próximo(`método next`), como em um tela de login, ao clicar nele você será enviado para outra dela através da Invocação Explicita.

- As intenções explícitas especificam o componente a iniciar pelo nome
  (o nome de classe totalmente qualificado). Normalmente, usa-se uma
  intenção explícita para iniciar um componente no próprio aplicativo
  porque se sabe o nome de classe da atividade ou serviço que se deseja
  iniciar. Por exemplo, iniciar uma nova atividade em resposta a uma
  ação do usuário ou iniciar um serviço para baixar um arquivo em
  segundo plano.

---

Para chamar sua Activity implicitamente:

Modifique a sua activity `.EmailActivity` no seu arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.intents">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".NomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".EmailActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

Modifique, adicionando o `intent-filter`:

```
                <activity android:name=".EmailActivity">

                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="br.com.intents.android.intent.action.EMAIL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>

                </activity>
```

No método `next`, no Arquivo `NomeActivity.java`, modifique assim:

```
 public void next(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent("br.com.intents.android.intent.action.EMAIL");
    startActivity(intent); 

    }
```

- As intenções implícitas não nomeiam nenhum componente específico, mas
  declaram uma ação geral a realizar, o que permite que um componente
  de outro aplicativo a trate. Por exemplo: se você deseja exibir ao
  usuário uma localização em um mapa, pode usar uma intenção implícita
  para solicitar que outro aplicativo capaz exiba uma localização
  especificada no mapa.

---

Quando invocar explicitamente:

> Chamada fixa de uma activity, simples, usado por padrão.

Quando invocar implicitamente:

> Quando você quiser chamar uma `activity` que sabe que ela pode ser
>   substituída por outra `activity`(flexibilidade) ou algum recurso
>   nativo do android ou serviço de terceiro.

Veja o guia do Android Developer: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html